# Why is it saying i'm misplacing "elif" even though i already have "if" and "else" in the script?

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2(0,0)

const SPEED = 100

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        velocity.x = SPEED
        $Sprite.play("right")
        
        move_and_slide(velocity)

    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x,0,0.1)
        
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        velocity.x = -SPEED
        $Sprite.play("left")
        
        move_and_slide(velocity)

    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x,0,0.1)

    if Input.is_action_pressed("up"):
        velocity.y = -SPEED
        $Sprite.play("up")
        
        move_and_slide(velocity)

    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0,0.1)
    
    **elif** Input.is_action_pressed("down"):
        velocity.y = SPEED
        $Sprite.play("down")
    else:
        $Sprite.play("idle")
        
        move_and_slide(velocity)

    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0,0.1)
```

im super new to this, started 2 days ago and am super confused :/ this is in godot btw

Comment: I want to point out that `velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x,0,0.1)` is equivalent to `velocity.x *= 9`. It decelerates (ignoring delta). But looks more fancy than it is. The fact that you are using it suggest to me you are copying it without knowing what it is. *I have seen it before, I wish I knew who is spreading that. Also who is still suggesting to tag GDScript as Python? Can we stop it?* Anyway, do yourself a favor a get better study material. The official documentation has a section with links to third party resources: [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/community/tutorials.html).

Answer (score 0):

The  `elif` is misplaced as `velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y,0,0.1)` is breaking the flow for elif.
replace `elif` with `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Python is all about indentation. Your `elif` is indented the same as the code line above it (the `velocity.y = ...`)

Because the `velocity.y =` line is the same indentation as the above `if` statement, it effectively "closes out" the above `if`. So your `elif` has no accompanying `if`.

My quick guess is that your `velocity.y =` line needs to be indented further, to match the  `move_and_slide(velocity)` line. Doing that there (and in other places) should solve your immediate problem.

Without studying your code more closely, my other quick guess is that you may be able to do what you want with a single if-elif-elif-else tree, but I leave that up to you.  Usually in a case like yours, you're checking for a few different conditions, but only one of them can occur. In such a situation, an if-elif-else tree may be a good way to go.

In your situation, watch out for your last `else` statement. You could  change the problematic `elif` to an `if` (like another colleague's answer suggests), but then you may likely be triggering the `else` statement when it probably shouldn't be triggered.

I think the `if right -- elif left -- elif up -- elif down -- else` is the best way to go.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Except this is not Python. We are looking at GDScript. *I thought the age of tagging GDScript as Python to try to get more eyes on the question was over. But here we are.*

Comment: @Theraot - my oversight (and bad eyesight)... different language but sufficiently similar syntax, and same logic. :)

Comment: It is not on you. The question was tagged Python. And yes, they are similar enough for the situation at hand.

Comment: @Gary02127 , i tried this, but it continues to say "elif" is misplaced!! I forgot to mention earlier, not sure if this info is needed, but with the first script it just crashed when i put the "else : $Sprite.play("idle")". I changed the script a bit after reading the answers, and after changing "func _physics_process(delta):" to "func _process(delta):", it runs, but takes away the up, left, and right animations and disables movement downward. Im sure the reason this happened is because i dont have "elif" in the script, but the problem is that it wont let me place them. Any advice on this?